# Font-Weight CSS Transition in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, css-transitions

Trying to get `font-weight` to gracefully transition from '400' to '600' using CSS but it doesn't appear to be working in Chrome.  Is this a known bug or am I doing something wrong?

[Check the Fiddle here for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/r4gDh/1/)

Comment: would be nice to show us what you've done so far so we could analyze your code, to tell if you did something wrong or not

Comment: It doesn't work in IE10 either. `font-weight` is supposed to be animatable, but I'm not sure if any browser's font rendering engine supports it.

Comment: hmmm...  It does seem to work in Firefox/Opera.  Annoying...

Comment: I seem to get a transition on font-weight when setting transition:all... (Chrome, FF and IE11)
OK... it does look like a transition for quick transitions. Try .25s

Comment: Ah, never mind, it's a visual effect because I'm doing a transition on color too. If you do a transition on color (ex: from gray to blue) and switch to bold at the same time, the transition looks smooth.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Font-weight animation is currently not supported in Chrome and IE-10 based on numerous tests.  This may change in the future.

Comment: We are now in the future but a variable font is required for this to work.

Answer (score 66):

The problem is that font weights, when represented numerically, must be a multiple of 100. To animate between 400 and 600, the font would change from 400 to 500 to 600 (3 'frames', if you like) and wouldn't look very smooth. An animation wouldn't increment the weight by 1 each time (400, 401, 402...) it would increment the weight by 100 (400, 500, 600). If your animation lasted 2 seconds, after 1 second the weight would suddenly become 500, and after 2 seconds the weight would suddenly become 600; there are no in-between variations.

A further problem with what you're attempting here is that the font you're using (or JSFiddle's default, at least) doesn't have anything different for `font-weight:500`, meaning it defaults to 400:

```
<p style="font-weight:400;">a - 400, normal</p>
<p style="font-weight:500;">a - 500 (no support, defaults to 400)</p>
<p style="font-weight:600;">a - 600 (bold)</p>
<p style="font-weight:650;">a - 650 (not valid, defaults to 400)</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r4gDh/6/

> Numeric font weights for fonts that provide more than just normal and bold. If the exact weight given is unavailable, then 600-900 use the closest available darker weight (or, if there is none, the closest available lighter weight), and 100-500 use the closest available lighter weight (or, if there is none, the closest available darker weight). This means that for fonts that provide only normal and bold, 100-500 are normal, and 600-900 are bold.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight

This basically means that you can't smoothly animate `font-weight`. Even if you had support for all weights between 100 and 900 the change wouldn't be pleasant and there would be a dramatic change between 500 and 600 (where *lighter weight* meets *darker weight*).

Comment: In Chrome, it's not animating at all, but in FF/Opera it animates.  "Smoothness" is a matter of relativity and while I hear what you're saying (and read the source docs you linked to), I don't think that's the issue here.  I think it's just not currently supported in Chrome/IE10.

Comment: The only difference I can see between Firefox and Chrome is that Chrome applies `font-weight:600` at the beginning of the animation, and Firefox applies it at the end.

Comment: Even if you change the font to a known robust family, and set the non-hovered state to a weight of '100' and the hovered state to a weight of '900', it still applies 900 immediately, which means that that transition most likely isn't supported.

Comment: Chrome Canary does the same as the stable version, so it's either a design decision to not implement it or a bug. I'd imagine it's probably more of a design decision more than anything, however. I've updated your JSFiddle to use a font with support for 400, 500 and 600, and the jumps between each weight variation are clearly visible (using Firefox): http://jsfiddle.net/r4gDh/9/

Comment: yah, if you do it with Open Sans and reduce the time to 300ms, it actually looks pretty decent (in FF).  Anyway, sucks that they aren't supporting it in Chrome.  Thanks for putting in the time.

Answer (score 40):

I came here to find out the answer myself for how to transition font weight, and was disappointed when I read the approved answer above saying that it can't be done (or at least not very well).

With font-weight animation unavailable, I decided to try another effect, which actually gives you a font-weight effect... which I didn't even think would work for this type of transition.

Here is how to make the weight grow:

```
.weightGrow:hover {
    text-shadow:
    -1px -1px 0 #2DD785,
    1px -1px 0 #2DD785,
    -1px 1px 0 #2DD785,
    1px 1px 0 #2DD785;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}
```

Perfectly smooth and exactly what I was looking for when I first arrived on this page. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: cheers, for others reading, its worth playing around with the 1px and change to .3px or .4px etc if needed

Comment: Nice mate! You can increase little bit of font-size if shadow fills up the counters.

Comment: Tried but it seems pixelated. Not much pleasing.

Comment: `text-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 0 currentColor` is a more subtle variant that also adjusts to the text color.

Comment: This is a good answer because it even though the direct answer is "no, you can't", this one says "you can't, but this gets you close."  I (personally) love answers like that.

Answer (score 9):

Fonts are not simple vector image collections (that's why svg fonts never took off). Opentype fonts include all kinds of magic to clamp fonts to the pixel grid, which makes it unrealistic to expect a font family to ever include every possible weight value.

Because fonts are not simple vector image collections they will also never resize linearly – there will be bumps to take the pixel grid into account.

This Google whitepaper explains why linear resizing does not work for text on current screens
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wpzgGMqXgit6FBVaO76epnnFC_rQPdVKswrDQWyqO1M/edit

which is why no browser will attempt it and they will all rely on pre-computed font weights.

That may change in a decade when retina displays are the lowest common denominator but current font tech targets current screens.

This Microsoft whitepaper documents some standard font weight values
http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-02-24-90-36/WPF-Font-Selection-Model.pdf

(but just because they are documented does not mean the number of fonts that actually include all of them is not quite small)

You can probably achieve the effect you want with an svg font and some javascript. The svg font will be crap for text use though.

Answer (score 5):

I seem to have obtained a "font-weight" transition effect accidentally, by doing a quick color transition (light gray to dark blue) at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

Smooth font-weight transitions and animations are possible using variable fonts which are not limited to increments of 100. More info on variable fonts here: https://web.dev/variable-fonts/

Try this snippet with eg. https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Raleway

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Raleway Flex';
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v29/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyC0ITw.woff2) format('woff2');
  font-weight: 100 900;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Raleway Flex', sans-serif;
  animation: example 1s linear 0s infinite alternate both;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {
    font-weight: 100;
  }
  to {
    font-weight: 900;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>HELLO</h1>
<p>I look way smoother if you use a variable font.</p>
```

Comment: Both in chrome and firefox I only see 3 different states.

Answer (score 2):

Although there is no direct way to get the font-weight to smoothly transition, I have found a way to do this indirectly (although with some limitations).

In essence you can simply use one of the pseudo elements in order to make a mirror copy of the element whom font you want to transition to bold, where the font-weight on the pseudo element is bold and the opacity is 0. And on hover simply transition the pseudo element's opacity and that does the trick with a very smooth transition.

You can see a demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/r4gDh/45/

HTML:

```
<div class="element" data-text="text will turn to bold on hover">
  text will turn to bold on hover
</div>
```

In the HTML you can already see one of the limitations, because we are using pseudo elements we need to pass the contents of the element as an attribute as well, so the content is duplicated.

CSS:

```
.element,
.element::before {
    background: red;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:40px;

    text-align:center;

    display: inline-block;

    padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;

    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.element::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    padding: 0;

    content: attr(data-text);
    opacity: 0;

    font-weight: bold;

    transition: all 1s linear;
}
.element:hover::before {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The second limitation comes from the nature of the technique, namely because you are simply overlaying the pseudo element over the original, then the element needs to have a solid background or this will not work, because the original element will remain visible in the background.

One thing you should really keep an eye on is that the pseudo element and the original element have the same dimensions, to this end, in the demo, I've removed the padding on the pseudo element, so you may need to do something similar.

As you can see, this way of getting the font-weight transition is not without it's problems and far from ideal, but this is the best I can currently think of and in limited cases like for buttons and what not this is quite useful and if done correctly will look decent even in legacy browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I've tweaked @Idra's fiddle to make the normal to bold transition a bit smoother. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y7rLwx95/

Changes... Since the text width will get wider when going to bold, I've added an initial "stretch" transition by increasing the letter spacing:

```
.element:hover {
   letter-spacing: 0.9px;
   transition: all .3s linear;
}
```

Then delayed the fading in of the bold ::before element:

```
.element:hover::before {
   opacity: 1;
   transition-delay: .2s
}
```

Also some additional tweaks here:

```
.element::before {
   transition: all .3s linear;  /* replace */
   letter-spacing: 0;           /* additional */
}
```

The transition timing is just whatever feels right to me. The original idea @Idra posted is significant to me. I accept that fact that the widths **should** be different between normal and bold, as that's the intent of different font weights. So really the challenge, IMHO, is to figure out how to go between the 2 looks in a smooth, no jarring way. This seems to be the best solution so far I've found.

Answer (score 0):

Complemented the answer from @user2943492

now i use this SASS mixin to help me to create this efect

```
@mixin hover-weight-grow($offset: 0.2px, $color: currentColor, $time: 0.3s) {
  &:hover {
    text-shadow:
      -$offset -$offset 0 $color,
      $offset -$offset 0 $color,
      -$offset $offset 0 $color,
      $offset $offset 0 $color;
    transition: all $time ease-in-out;
  }
}
```