# transition on link using delay all doesn't work

Tags: css

what is wrong with `transition: all 0.7s linear;` here?

I want to change the font-weight when I hover onto the link.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uVfPF/)**.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is caused by non-linear nature of font-weight.

Although it may be represented by numbers (100, 200, 300, ...), browsers have no idea how to display the different weights.

Trying with different numeric properties works as expected (at least in Chrome browser ;))

**EDIT:**

I've found [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629725/font-weight-css-transition-in-chrome) on SO

Answer (score 0):

Seem like font-weight animation by pure CSS is not supported in any browser. However if you're allowed to use javascript, you can use `setTimeout` to animate the `font-weight` smoothly. Here is the way to go:

```
Text.hover(
  function() {
      Text.css({'font-weight':200});
      setTimeout(function(){ Text.css({'font-weight':300})}, 30)
      setTimeout(function(){ Text.css({'font-weight':400})}, 60)
      setTimeout(function(){ Text.css({'font-weight':500})}, 90)
      setTimeout(function(){ Text.css({'font-weight':600})},120)
      setTimeout(function(){ Text.css({'font-weight':700})},150)
      setTimeout(function(){ Text.css({'font-weight':800})},180)
      setTimeout(function(){ Text.css({'font-weight':900})},210)
  }, function() {
      Text.css({'font-weight':800});
      setTimeout(function(){ Text.css({'font-weight':700})}, 30)
      setTimeout(function(){ Text.css({'font-weight':600})}, 60)
      setTimeout(function(){ Text.css({'font-weight':500})}, 90)
      setTimeout(function(){ Text.css({'font-weight':400})},120)
      setTimeout(function(){ Text.css({'font-weight':300})},150)
      setTimeout(function(){ Text.css({'font-weight':200})},180)
      setTimeout(function(){ Text.css({'font-weight':100})},210)
  }
);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tfAFh/)

Comment: Please remember that the font you choosed has more than just "normal" and "bold" state, that's why it's possible.