# Why won't CSS transitions function for font-weight?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply a transition for a hyperlink's font-weight to gradually increase it upon user hover.

```css
.header a {
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 100;
  transition: font-weight 1s ease-in-out;
}

.header a:hover {
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a href="#About">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

When I hover over the element, the font-weight changes after the given time (1 second). However, the transition simply has no effect. That is, it immediately changes from a font-weight of 100 to 900, and vice-versa. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font-Weight CSS Transition in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629725/font-weight-css-transition-in-chrome)

Comment: I saw that and it was of no use to me

Comment: fwiw, `font-weight` [is an animatable property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)

Answer (score 0):

After some trys this is the solution:

Apperently you HAVE TO include some font-family fo the transition to work. 
Like so:

```
font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
```

```css
.header a {
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  transition: font-weight 1s ease-in-out;
}

.header a:hover {
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a href="#About">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

P.S.: I think this is due to the different sizes of letters & spaces etc..., that the browser needs to know the specific font-family in order to resize the font-weight accordingly.