# The time portion of my transition is not elapsing before the transition completes

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions, transition

```css
nav {
  background-color: black;
}
nav ul {
    grid-column: 5;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
nav li {
    display: inline;
}
nav li a {
    color: white;
    font-family: Comic Sans MS;
    font-size: .9em;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out; 
}
nav li a:hover {
    font-weight: 900;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out; 
}
```

```html
<nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

So I have set `transition: all .5s ease-in-out;` (see the .5 second) but still, when hovering on the links it will just go straight into the hover state without a transition. How come?

Answer (score 4):

You need to establish an initial value for the font-weight (non-hover state), and import all the font-weights between the original font-weight, and the font-weight on hover. See https://codepen.io/madshensel/pen/ZOYwpy for an example.

If you use a web based font, you can import them like:

```
@import url(<font-url-goes-here>:400,900,800,700,600,500,300,200,100);
```

Then in `nav li a`, add `font-weight: 400`

Comment: This requires the import of any font you'd like to accomplish this with, but great solution! +1

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an issue with your transition itself per-se, but really an issue with font weight transitions. There have been a few posts on it on the web but here is a really [great work around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629725/font-weight-css-transition-in-chrome).

I've added a color change to your `a:hover` class, along with removed the unneccesary transition that was there too.

```css
nav {
  background-color: #333;
}
nav ul {
    grid-column: 5;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
nav li {
    display: inline;
}
nav li a {
    color: white;
    font-family: Comic Sans MS;
    font-size: .9em;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out; 
}
nav li a:hover {
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #f33;
}
```

```html
<nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

As you can see the transitions are working fine. There is currently (3 SEP 19) no way to smoothly transition font weights. However, there are many work-arounds and I've updated your snippet with a work around using `letter-spacing`. Since the font widens when the weight changes you can couple this with a `font-size` increase to get some nice effects.