# How can I fix shaky CSS animation of text shadow on hover?

Tags: html, css, animation, hover, shadow

I try to scale up the font size, while simultaneously scaling the shadow down.

This is what happens:

[image]

It is shaking at the beginning and at the end. The effect is very strong in my browser, but the included code snippet does not seem to behave exactly the same. How can I fix this shaking and get a natural looking animation?

```css
.heading-primary {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4.5rem;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.heading-primary__letter {
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 9%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 1s;
  position: relative;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.heading-primary__letter--shadow {
  color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  text-shadow: 0.5rem 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transition: all 1s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.heading-primary__letter:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
}

.heading-primary__letter:hover > .heading-primary__letter--shadow {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.8);
  text-shadow: 0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}

}
```

```html
<h1 class="heading-primary">
    <span class="heading-primary__letter">H<span class="heading-primary__letter--shadow">H</span></span>
</h1>
```

Comment: Try using css `will-change`, also try use a mere shadow, instead of second H.
One of options will possibly bring your H to more smooth behavior.

Comment: Can I scale the shadow down, while scaling the letter up? Because this is the effect that I want to achieve. I could not do that by just scaling the letter.

Comment: I have tried `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased`, `transform: scale(1) translateZ(0)`, none of those worked

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is the font-weight issue explained better than I can on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629725/font-weight-css-transition-in-chrome), another is the approach of having 2 different animations running and trying to wrestle that into working correctly. Put together a jsFiddle of some code that might help.

https://jsfiddle.net/SyWill/fwxLq7rt/6/

```
    /*Html Portion*/
    /* -Added link pointing to a font that has the weights to make a decent transition */
    /* -Removed Your secondary inner span in favor of just transitioning the text shadow*/

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet" />
        <h1 class="heading-primary">
            <span class="heading-primary__letter">H</span>
        </h1>

/*CSS Portion*/
/* -Added font-family to reference the new font we brought in */
/* -Added arbitrary start value for the text-shadow so you could see it grow */
/* -Added transition timing to try and smooth out the effect, still could use tweaking*/
/* -Removed all code relevant to the secondary H */

.heading-primary {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4.5rem;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  font-family:"Lato";
}

.heading-primary__letter {
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 9%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 1.4s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 0.999);
  position: relative;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  text-shadow: 0.2rem 0.2rem 0.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.heading-primary__letter:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  text-shadow: 0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}
```

Hope it helps!