# Element bouncing effect

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I can't figure out what properties should be added to the elements to remove the jumping effect (I want to fix it). Maybe you should use grid? All parameters should remain as they are (the font cannot be changed)

```css
.nav-list {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.navlist__item:first-child > .nav-list__link {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.nav-list__item:last-child > .nav-list__link {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.nav-list__link {
  display: inline-block;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 19px;
}

.nav-list__link:focus {
  color: #8428f8;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li class="nav-list__item">
      <a class="nav-list__link" href="#about">About me</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-list__item">
      <a class="nav-list__link" href="#experience">Experience</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-list__item">
      <a class="nav-list__link" href="#skills">Skills</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-list__item">
      <a class="nav-list__link" href="#projects">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-list__item">
      <a class="nav-list__link" href="#cv">CV</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be both a vertical and horizontal "jump" taking place.

For the vertical jump, I think you'll need `align-items: baseline` on the flex container.

For the horizontal jump, the root cause seems to be the `font-weight` transition. Unfortunately, without [variable fonts](https://v-fonts.com/), a truly smooth animation is impossible (and the original question asked to not change the font). However, a *similar* (not identical) effect can be achieved using `text-shadow`. The original idea for this workaround came from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35959226/2977638).

Both solutions listed above are demonstrated in the snippet below.

```css
.nav-list {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.navlist__item:first-child > .nav-list__link {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.nav-list__item:last-child > .nav-list__link {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.nav-list__link {
  display: inline-block;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 19px;
}

.nav-list__link:focus {
  color: #8428f8;
  text-shadow:
    -0.2px -0.2px 0 #8428f8,
    0.2px -0.2px 0 #8428f8,
    -0.2px 0.2px 0 #8428f8,
    0.2px 0.2px 0 #8428f8;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li class="nav-list__item">
      <a class="nav-list__link" href="#about">About me</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-list__item">
      <a class="nav-list__link" href="#experience">Experience</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-list__item">
      <a class="nav-list__link" href="#skills">Skills</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-list__item">
      <a class="nav-list__link" href="#projects">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-list__item">
      <a class="nav-list__link" href="#cv">CV</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This trick did not work, the elements are not static anyway.

Comment: Ah, are you looking for the font weight to animate smoothly as well? Without using a variable font, that specific transition might be impossible to achieve. If you are interested in trying some slightly hacky CSS workarounds, you could attempt a shadow transition to get a similar (though not identical) end effect: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35959226/2977638

Comment: I expanded on the previous comment in the answer. It's not the prettiest solution, but hopefully it provides a good foundation for working around both the horizontal and vertical "jumping."

Comment: I used the solution you suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the jumping effect when the link is clicked, you can add *outline: none;* to the *.nav-list__link:focus* selector. If not, change or remove *transition: all 0.3s;*

Comment: Transition is necessary. The outline trick didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent this behavior you can use `transform` property with `scale`. You can read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform).

Snippet:

```css
.nav-list {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.navlist__item:first-child > .nav-list__link {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.nav-list__item:last-child > .nav-list__link {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.nav-list__link {
  display: inline-block;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 19px;
}

.nav-list__link:focus {
  color: #8428f8;
  /*
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 16px;
  */
  transform: scale(1.1); 
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li class="nav-list__item">
      <a class="nav-list__link" href="#about">About me</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-list__item">
      <a class="nav-list__link" href="#experience">Experience</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-list__item">
      <a class="nav-list__link" href="#skills">Skills</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-list__item">
      <a class="nav-list__link" href="#projects">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-list__item">
      <a class="nav-list__link" href="#cv">CV</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I don't need to make the bouncing effect, but rather remove it.

Comment: When you write " jumping effect" you mean the style applied to the links when you click on it? If so why do you have the `.nav-list__link:focus` part? My solution based on the thought that you want to style it differently when you click on it.

Comment: The problem was with changing the font weight on focus. To use it, you need variable fonts. I used the method suggested by RNanoware